# Popping UINavigationController to a UITableView and displaying a different selected row

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller, popviewcontroller

I am creating an application with a `UITableView` being the first item on the stack of the `UINavigationController` that it's in. Making a selection on the `UITableView` will push the view to a "`DetailedViewController`". In the `DetailedViewController`, you can navigate through items that the table view is populated with.

When popping the `DetailedViewController`, and moving back to the `UITableView`, how can I deselect the respective item that I've navigated to through the `DetailedViewController` and display it centered in the `UITableView`?

An example that everyone can see would be the Mail application. When you're in your inbox and make a selection, you push a "`DetailedViewController`". There, you can navigate through the items populated in the `UITableView`. When you pop the `DetailedViewController`, it deselects the respective item that you were looking at last in the `DetailedViewController`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To deselect the selected row, write the following code `viewDidAppear:` method.

```
// Index path for selected row
NSIndexPath *selectedRow = [_tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

// Deselet the row with animation
[_tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:selectedRow animated:YES];

// Scroll the selected row to the center
[_tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:selectedRow 
       atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle 
               animated:YES];
```

Comment: How can you pass the selected row from the DetailedViewController that you pushed. I can't use delegates because my TableView uses delegates from the DetailedViewController

Comment: Okay I got it to work. I used a delegate method to pass the row back from the detailedview when viewwilldisappear. Then i put scrolltorow in the viewwillappear and then deselected when the viewdidappear.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you want the animation to look you could simply deselect your currently selected row.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
     [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
     ...
}
```

Comment: this wasn't really what i was looking for, but I did have to use this in combination with the other code.